# Confusion in loops

Tags: javascript, loops, while-loop

If I put 'let tableValue' outside a *while* loop then it shows the same number 10 times and when I write it inside the *while* loop then it prints a table of the value 'n'.

What is the difference between these two things?

```js
function table(n) {
  let i = 1;
  let tableValue = (n * i);
  while (i <= 10) {
    console.log(tableValue);
    i++;
  }
}
table(9);
```

```js
function table(n) {
  let i = 1;
  while (i <= 10) {
    let tableValue = (n * i);
    console.log(tableValue);
    i++;
  }
}
table(9);
```

Comment: You're not updating/setting the value inside the loop on the first one.

Comment: What's hard to understand about it? If you don't reassign `tableValue` it doesn't change.

Comment: Related: [Is JavaScript a pass-by-reference or pass-by-value language?](/q/518000/4642212). Why do you expect the two snippets to behave the same? Why do you believe the first one shouldn’t print `9` nine times? What do you think should happen instead? Why? [Rubber Duck Debug](//rubberduckdebugging.com/) your code. Please try using the [debugging capabilities](//ali-dev.medium.com/how-to-easily-debug-in-javascript-5bac70f94f1a) of your browser. Don’t just ask “Why are these different?”. Tell us why you believe they shouldn’t be. Otherwise, we’ll just say “Read the [spec](//tc39.es/ecma262)”.

Comment: Duplicate of [Javascript - change variable value that is part of another variables definition](/q/42637782/4642212).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you put this line:

```
let tableValue = (n * i);
```

outside your loop, as you have in the first example, then `tableValue` is set once, before the loop begins, and when you log it, you are logging the same value each time, because you never change it after that.

This statement is not a declaration that `tableValue` is *always* `n * i` at all times, even when `n` and `i` change. If you want that, you need to recalculate `tableValue` whenever either of the values changes. That's what you're accomplishing by putting that line inside your loop.

Computers execute code one line at a time and don't look ahead or backward much. When code changes your program's state, such as setting a variable value, that change persists until it is later changed again.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
function table(n) {
  let i = 1;
  let tableValue = (n * i); // This is 1 * 9, because it is outside the while loop ( the while loop block } don’t worry that it's inside the function, it still needs to be in the while block. I think that’s why you're getting confused.
  while (i <= 10) {
     console.log(tableValue);
     i++;
  }
}
table(9);
```

I’ve put comments on the line in which I think needs explaining.